# Number of ordered pairs satisfying given conditions

Tags: inequality

The number of pairs (a,b) of positive real numbers satisfying $$a^4+b^4<1$$ and $$a^2+b^2>1$$

I have done this by making a graph and shading the solution region.
I found that there are infinite solutions

I just wanted to know if there is any analytical method to 
Solve it.

Any suggestions on how to do it are welcome.

Comment: How did you draw the graph without studying the inequalities?

Anyway in either of the inequalities, fix 'a' and express 'b' in terms of 'a'. In this way you will get a pair (a, "expression of b in terms of 'a'") that describes the solution to the inequality.

Also I don't think this problem is about "graph-theory"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a=\cos^{\frac{2}{3}}(\alpha)$ and $b=\sin^{\frac{2}{3}}(\alpha)$

where $a,b\in(0,1)$ and let $\alpha\in(0,90^\circ)$

Then we have

$$a^4+b^4 <a^3+b^3=1<a^2+b^2$$

getting  infinite positive integer ordered pair of $(a,b)$

Answer (score 1):

Take $b=\frac  12$ for example. Then you need $a^{2} >\frac  3 4$ and $a^{4} <\frac  {15} {16}$. That means $\frac  3 4 <a^{2} <\frac  {\sqrt {15}} 4$. Can you now see that there are infintely many pairs of the type $(a,\frac  1 2)$ satisfying the given inequalities?